# Xamarin iOS UIButton How To Click button programmatically?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uibutton, performselector

I'm attempting to fake the act of clicking a button, by programmatically calling it within my ViewWillAppear() function.

The onclick function is defined in my ViewDidLoad(), and you can see I am trying to use a Perform Selector to manually call the button.

The button does not appear to be running. Any ideas?

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    idButtonScanLoad.TouchUpInside += async (sender, ea) =>
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Scan button pressed");
    };

}

[Export("TouchUpInsideEvent:")]
private void TouchUpInsideEvent(NSObject sender)
{
    Console.WriteLine("yay!");
}

public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    this.PerformSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("TouchUpInsideEvent:"), this as NSObject, 10f);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer, you should call it from your ViewDidLoad method.

```
myButton.SendActionForControlEvents (UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);
```

Comment: But wouldn't adding it to ViewDidLoad() mean the button would only be clicked the first time the View is loaded? What about when someone wants to go back to that View to use it again?

Comment: Use the same in ViewWillAppear but first of all check if the button is not null, if it is not this means that the user went back to that view.

Comment: I tried using it from other methods also it works .. not necessary it has to be called from ViewDidLoad but it has to be called from main thread

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a button's click event, you can use the this

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
     Mybutton.AddTarget(ButtonEventHandler, UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);
}

public void ButtonEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender==Mybutton)
    {
       //do stuff here
    }
}
```