# How to render a UIButton in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uibutton, renderer

How do I render a UIButton in Xamarin.iOS? See the current [Code](https://github.com/Jakar510/Jakar.SettingsView/blob/update_iOS_API/src/SettingsView.iOS/Cells/CommandCells/ButtonCellRenderer.cs) for the full list.

This is the code I'm using to create and add the button to the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CellTableViewCell` cell. I cannot get the button to display anything.
With the use of a `Foundation.NSMutableAttributedString`, it shows a cut-off section of text in the top left corner, regardless of anything I try (alignments, insets, bounds, various constraints, etc). I'm currently trying things from [Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Renderers.ButtonRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/8b10f11651b85b2821214b786f7a101a8b3c81e0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ButtonRenderer.cs), but still can't get anything to display at all, no text, no button, or its outline.

If you could fork the repo and fix it or post the solution here, I would be very grateful.

```
protected override void SetUpContentView()
{
    var insets = new UIEdgeInsets(SVConstants.Cell.PADDING.Top.ToNFloat(), SVConstants.Cell.PADDING.Left.ToNFloat(), SVConstants.Cell.PADDING.Bottom.ToNFloat(), SVConstants.Cell.PADDING.Right.ToNFloat());
    _Button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect)
              {
                  AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All,
                  HorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center,
                  VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center,
                  ContentEdgeInsets = insets,
                  // TitleEdgeInsets = insets
              };

    DefaultFontSize = _Button.TitleLabel.ContentScaleFactor;
    DefaultTextColor = _Button.TitleLabel.TextColor;

    _Recognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(RunLong);
    _Button.TouchUpInside += OnClick;          // https://stackoverflow.com/a/51593238/9530917
    _Button.AddGestureRecognizer(_Recognizer); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179591/9530917


    ContentView.AddSubview(_Button);
    _Button.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;
    _Button.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;

    _Button.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.WidthAnchor).Active = true;
    _Button.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.HeightAnchor).Active = true;

    UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded();
    LayoutIfNeeded();
}
```

Comment: Also the GitHub issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14022

Comment: Could you show me a screenshot of the effect you want ?

Comment: What i'd like, honestly for both android and ios, is https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/beautiful-material-design-android-ios/

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT But anything that shows up at this point is ok.

Comment: Found out that you can't subclass it. Any button added to the view must be native (UIButton) or custom rendered, such as Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer; It doesn't show up otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that you can't subclass it. Any button added to the view must be native (UIButton) or custom rendered, such as Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer; It doesn't show up otherwise.